# How do I PREVENT ActiveRecord from normalizing a DateTime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, activerecord

This is sort of the opposite of almost all questions about timestamps in Rails and ActiveRecord.

I want to record a date+time+time-zone datum from an outside source. I want to retain the time zone information because it is important to identify the *where* as well the when. All of the straightforward implementations convert any timestamp to UTC, which is absolutely "the right thing to do"™️ but in this situation, I don't want to lose the timezone information.

Postgres 9.x and 10.x

Comment: you could save the value as string instead?

Comment: You can totally store Timezones information via: ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone. If thats still too 'static', you need to create columns and store the timezone as a string. If you need Timezones later on for dynamic things, ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone is probably the best choice.

Comment: What database are you using and what kind of columns? If you look at postgres for example it has timestamp and timestamptz (with a time zone) data types. Mysql on the other hand goes about the problem by ignoring it completely.

Comment: Another attempt could be to store the time zone independently from the timestamp in a separate column. That way, you don't have to work around rails behaviour to store timestamps as UTC and can access the time zone information independently as well.